# When running asp.net project through an IIS localhost instace, it fails to load any css files

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2013

The problem is that it fails to find any css files and thus the pages render horribly.

In the head section of my master page, I have the following line:

```
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
```

When I debug from the IDE and look at PageSource, the above translates to:

```
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap-override.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

When I point IIS to the project and run using localhost, I get no css applied and the PageSource translates to:

```
<link href="/QM/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/QM/Content/bootstrap-override.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/QM/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

"QM" is the Alias I chose when I created the Application in IIS.

My question: Where is the "/QM" prefix coming from and how do I suppress it?

I'm sure I'm just missing something in my IIS setup or perhaps web.config, but I have been unable to find any help from previous questions or the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is often the case, I was reading the symptoms wrong, misinterpreting what was important and not getting any help. Here's what I found:

First, I found that I could get the /QM prefix when running from the IDE as well by adding it in the Project URL on the Properties window of the Project. So that wasn't the problem at all.

What was wrong was that the IIS installation (Turn Windows features on or off) did not have Static Content installed so that even though the Handler Mappings had a handler for StaticFile (already there) it wasn't able to load because that part of IIS wasn't installed. Once it was, my page loaded as expected.